# Given a month and a year, return the number of days

Tags: java

The program is supposed to take a month and a year, and then return the number of days; however, it just asks for a couple more inputs and then gives output. I think the problem is with the `Scanner` instance, since I have tried with giving preset values, such as `month = 2` and `year = 2000`, and it worked fine.

```
public static int getNumberofDays(int month, int year) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    month = in.nextInt();
    year = in.nextInt();


    if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
        checking which month is it
        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 ||
                   month == 7 || month == 9 || month == 11)

        {
            return 31;
        } else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 8 ||
                          month == 10 || month == 12) {
            return 30;
        } else {
            return 29;
        }
    } else {
        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 ||
                   month == 9 || month == 11)

        {
            return 31;
        } else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 8 ||
                          month == 10 || month == 12)

        {
            return 30;
        } else {
            return 28;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using an odd calendar. Where in the world does September have 31 days, but August and October only 30?

Comment: Does your code actually just randomly have the phrase `checking which month is it` in it?

Comment: When I did the code formatting, I had to comment that bit out, as IntelliJ would stumble on it forever if I didn't.   I hope you have that commented out in your code.

Comment: I deleted all the comments when I pasted the code, this one seems to have slipped, I only erased the "//"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **weird**:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
month = in.nextInt();
year = in.nextInt();
```

You're instantiating a new `Scanner` in your class **and** setting the *parameters* to the next integer value from it.

Why would you pass values in if that were the case?

Ditch the `Scanner` declaration inside of that method, so that what you pass in will actually be used, and advance the `Scanner` appropriately.

This is to say nothing of the logic errors you have - the days in each month is not correct.  Case in point:   November has 30 days, yet your program will return 31.

Here's a sample.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Month?");
    int month = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Year?");
    int year = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(getNumberOfDays(month, year));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot. I randomly distributed days to months, in the beginning. Thank you again  :D